# Find the maximum values of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2y^2z^2$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=289$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have already figured out the majority of the problem. I took the derivative of $x$ and got: $x=0,y=0,z=0$. Initially I put that there were infinitely many solutions, but that is not true. I do not know where I went wrong as I took the derivatives in respect to $x$ and subtracted from the derivative of x to the $g(x)$. However, it gave me zero for all of my solutions.

I successfully found the minimum though.

Comment: Show your calculations...

Comment: Do you know the method of Lagrange's multiplier?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes! That's what I was using, but I don't know how to get the symbol on here.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I can't, I don't know how to get the symbol on here.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

With AM-GM$$x^2+y^2+z^2=289\ge3\cdot \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$ Thus $$\bigg(\frac{289}{3}\bigg)^3\geq x^2y^2z^2$$
Equality holds iff $\pm x=\pm y=\pm z$

---

## Detailed Explanation

> **Theorem 1**: *Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean (or simply AM-GM) inequality for three variables*
>
> > Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb R^+$, then $$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{a\cdot b\cdot c}$$

**Proof**

Substitute $a=d^3, b=e^3, c=f^3$. Observe now that

\begin{align*}
&d^3+e^3+f^3-3\cdot def=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (d+e+f)\cdot \big((d-e)^2+(e-f)^2+(f-d)^2\big)\ge0\tag{1}\\
\iff & d^3+e^3+f^3\ge 3\cdot def\\
\iff & a+b+c\ge 3\cdot \sqrt[3]{abc}
\end{align*}

You can check the equation in $(1)$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=boolean+d%5E3%2Be%5E3%2Bf%5E3-3*+def%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D*+(d%2Be%2Bf)*((d-e)%5E2%2B(e-f)%5E2%2B(f-d)%5E2)) or prove it yourself - it's up to you.

---

***Sidenote:*** Note that you'll only achive equality in $(1)$ if and only if $$d+e+f=0\qquad \text{or} \qquad (d-e)^2+(e-f)^2+(f-d)^2=0$$
i.e. if and only if $d=e=f\implies a=b=c$.

---

Now, back to your problem, observe that the function $f(x, y, z):=x^2\cdot y^2\cdot z^2$ can only take non-negative values as long as $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ - which I assume.

Thus - in virtue of the **Theorem 1** $$\frac{289}{3}=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2} $$

Comment: I don't understand how you did any of that and how that's relevant.

Comment: @AmyKulp I've edited the answer in order to provide a more detailed explanation of the AM-GM inequality. Please don't hesitate to ask if something isn't clear ;)

Comment: To the proposer: The AM-GM (or AGM) inequality is that if $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $x_1,...,x_n$ are non-negative reals then $(x_1+...+x_n)/n\le (x_1\cdot\, ... \,\cdot x_n)^{1/n}$ with equality iff $x_1=...=x_n.$ There are about a thousand ways to prove it.

Comment: Exactly @DanielWainfleet